# Meaning of two ADC channels in an LTR-559ALS-01 optical sensor

Tags: adc, light-sensor

I am using an LTR-559ALS-01 optical sensor to read the level of ambient light. Everything works, but from the [datasheet](https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS86-2013-0003/LTR-559ALS-01_DS_V1.pdf) I can't make out why there are two analog channels for said reading.

Both channels can be read and display a similar behavior when exposed to light (channel 2 has a slightly higher reading with low light levels but higher when brighter.) A lone table at the beginning seem to suggest that they have a different scale, but I'm not sure.

[image: light sensor]

It mentions a ratio between the two channels, but it's not explained further. Moreover, both channels are subject to the same gain configuration, so I don't think a different scale is the final purpose.

I would like to understand why there are two channels and if I should combine them in some way to get the real value. I might be missing something obvious here, but it's my first time working with this kind of sensor so I'm not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two channels are connected to two different light sensing diodes:

- One is sensitive to IR only
- The other is sensitive to IR + visible light

This gives you more flexibility in choosing what spectral range you are interested in. If you are only interested in visible light intensity you can simply subtract Ch1 from Ch0.

To be honest I'm not sure what this "ALS ratio" is supposed to to tell us, it will be different for different light sources. They specify that value for a "white LED", whatever that says about the spectrum...

[image]